# How to get the name of the property that is bound to datagrid column in wpf?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a datagrid with almost 30 columns, I need to get the name of the property that is bound to a column. I am using datagrid_selectedcellschanged(sender,selectedeventargs) event of the datagrid.

Comment: how you are binding the data to the datagrid?

Comment: via MVVM, list of a type

Comment: can you post that type and the code where you bind

Comment: DataGrid column uses `Binding` which has even a `Path` of type `PropertyPath`, that means the Path can be long (with multiple ***dots*** in the path). So what you can get is actually this path. How you use that path depends on you.

Comment: <DataGrid x:Name="peopleGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding PeopleList}">
<DataGrid.Columns>
<DataGridTextColumn Width="25*" Binding="{Binding PersonID}" CanUserReorder="False" Header="ID" IsReadOnly="True" />
</Datagrid>

Comment: @Sajeetharan thats the code i am using,  at king now i need to find the personid from code behind on selected cells changed, could u pls let me know how we do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure What you mean by *Name of the property* - **Column header** or **Cell Value**

If you mean the column header you can get it like this

```
string selectedColumnHeader = (string)myGrid.SelectedCells[0].Column.Header;
```

If you mean Cell Value you can get it like this

```
DataRowView dataRow = (DataRowView)dataGrid1.SelectedItem;
int index = datagrid1.CurrentCell.Column.DisplayIndex;
string cellValue= dataRow.Row.ItemArray[index].ToString();
```

Comment: when we use mvvm, we have to bind column to the property of the item or object that we are binding, so i wanted the property that i had binded this column to.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this on selectionChanged,

```
 private void peopleGrid_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
  {
         var selectedObj= peopleGrid.SelectedItem as YourObject;
         if(selectedObj != null)
         {
         int PersonID   = selectedObj.PersonID;
         }
  }
```

Comment: yes thanks for your help,but this doesnt help me as I have 30 columns or so, I would want the property dynamically.

Comment: @kedarK you should use reflection

Comment: i had to use column header as answered by carbinecoder

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I managed to resolve the same issue based on a data grid template column and using an editable column.

First is to cast the binding expression of the element being edited.  Next, retrieve the associated property name being displayed in the cell.

```
<DataGrid Name="dgMaterialSorter" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
          PreparingCellForEdit="dgMaterialSorter_PreparingCellForEdit" 
          CellEditEnding="dgMaterialSorter_CellEditEnding">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="" Binding="{Binding MaterialName}"  IsReadOnly="true" Width="Auto" HeaderStyle="{StaticResource GridHdr_Right}" CellStyle="{StaticResource GridCol_Right}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Code" Binding="{Binding MaterialCode}"  IsReadOnly="true" Width="Auto" HeaderStyle="{StaticResource GridHdr_Center}" CellStyle="{StaticResource GridCol_Center}" />
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Qty"  HeaderStyle="{StaticResource GridHdr_Center}" CellStyle="{StaticResource GridCol_Center}"  >
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Quantity}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBox x:Name="EditTextbox" Text="{Binding Quantity, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
```

```
private void dgMaterialSorter_CellEditEnding(object sender, DataGridCellEditEndingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.EditAction == DataGridEditAction.Commit)
    {

        BindingExpression binding = (BindingExpression)e.EditingElement.BindingGroup.BindingExpressions[0];
        string bindingField = binding.ResolvedSourcePropertyName;
        if (bindingField.Equals(nameof(MaterialSorter.Quantity))) { /*DO SOMETHING*/ }
    }
}
```